# Fastest way of retrieving a list in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have a database of some entries of type Father and some entries of type Son,
each Son belongs to his own Father, and each Father may have one or more Sons.

I have thought about using 2 methods, but I don't know which one is faster

1. Have a ForeignKey in each Son, named Father_ID, and when I want to retrieve a list of Sons of a Father, I will use WHERE, to reduce the number of sons of the specified father.
2. Have a middle table, to connect the Father table and the Son table,  each entry will be pointed to by the sons, and it will point to the Father, thus accessing the list of sons will be used by the "backref" option of the middle table

I would be grateful if someone could point me to the fastest way of doing it :)

Comment: Unless you want to model a son having multiple fathers, having the father foreign key in the son table would be faster and make a lot more sense.